# Actionscript to java source converter

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, converters

is there a tool which can convert actionscript3 source code to java source?

Comment: Given the Flash plug-in's great support for advanced media types, one huge challenge would be to supply the missing codecs, and support for the missing formats, within Java.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this page awhile ago because I needed an actionscript to java converter too.  I wrote one myself. It's very simple and requires manual adaptation after conversion (as most such converters do), but it does a good job of automating the boring stuff.  You can find it on
[my blog](http://www.borisvanschooten.nl/blog/2011/05/01/a-mini-actionscript-3-to-java-converter/).

Comment: the link to your blog is dead. Can you repost

Comment: I'm also interested in the converter, if you can upload it somewhere else, I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) (which has similar syntax to AS3, also based on the ECMA Specification) is able to compile to Java (as well as a slew of other languages and bytecodes). It requires learning a new language, but it may be worth it.

Comment: Sorry, seems like the Java compilation/translation is [still in progress](http://twitter.com/#!/cwaneck/status/15486381623091200). But [it's on it's way](http://twitter.com/#!/cwaneck/status/46650456000311296).

Answer (score 1):

You should explain why you want to convert from AS3 to Java. I think, the typically way is to convert from Java to AS3, e.g. with [Gas3](http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/3.+Gas3+Code+Generator).

Comment: He may want to convert if he using BlazeDS. It would be difficult to convert logic, but one can easily convert getters and setters of a Java object into an equivalent AS3 class.44

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to do this via Haxe in near future. First use [as3hx](http://code.google.com/p/haxe/source/browse/other) to convert AS3 to Haxe, and then you can convert Haxe to Java via Haxe compiler. Haxe/Java was promised to be relased in this year.