# Convert AS3 to Java

Tags: java, actionscript-3, gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Actionscript to java source converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322875/actionscript-to-java-source-converter)

I am looking for a tool that will help me convert code that I wrote in AS3 to Java. It doesn't have to be perfect just a tool that will do most of the work by replacing, for example:

```
var i:int = 0
```

with

```
int i = 0
```

The ultimate goal is to convert flash to gwt.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322875/actionscript-to-java-source-converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write simple regular expressions and then run a find / replace? for example, a reg exp to change variable declarations would be `var (.*?)\:(.*?)( \= )??(.*?)??\;` and replace it with `$2 $1$3$4`;

Check out http://www.borisvanschooten.nl/blog/2011/05/01/a-mini-actionscript-3-to-java-converter/

This does the same thing (with regular expressions) and you'll need to check its output